# Warm up for a new long code in MobileConnet?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, ip-warming

We've purchased a new long code for MobileConnect. We've been wondering if a warm up (sending messages in small quantities first and then gradually increasing the number) is necessary before using it for mass sends (~80k-100k sends per day).

i.e. if the same warm up process which should be done for IP warmup in Email Studio applies also to a new code used in MobileConnect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It’s not officially advised anywhere by Salesforce, but there are some external sources that recommend doing it:

> **Warm up your sending reputation**
>
> Similar to warming up your email sending reputation, you should warm
> up your text message sending number(s).
>
> Sending from a new number can cause recipients to opt-out, which may
> cause your message to get flagged as a carrier violation.
>
> When carriers see your text messages for the first time, it’s best to
> keep your messages simple and concise. Most importantly, don’t use
> links or any sales language.

This article gives a lot of tips for starting with SMS marketing: https://www.dailystory.com/blog/carrier-violations-what-to-avoid-doing-during-sms-text-marketing/